# How can I catch "Uncaught exception"?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing some fb app, using python-sdk.
Sometimes I get an "Uncaught exception", that looks like:

```
Uncaught exception GET…
…
…
GraphAPIError: Error validating access token.
```

I know the reasons for this exception, and how to solve it (renew oauth token).

But how can I catch it?

Traditional `try: .. except:` doesn't do it.

Looking for a solution without hacking the SDK code.

Full error output, as asked in the comments:

```
[E 110407 20:44:20 web:900] Uncaught exception GET /fl?access_token=122385271170470|2.teD_D9DV6gegmpgkbZI_Hg__.3600.1302206400-1592301191|GuXEs4YTqsCPDNFU4fhbWuwlvOQ (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPRequest(protocol='http', host='XX.XX.100.66', method='GET', uri='/fl?access_token=122385271170470|2.teD_D9DV6gegmpgkbZI_Hg__.3600.1302206400-1592301191|GuXEs4YTqsCPDNFU4fhbWuwlvOQ', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', body='', headers={'Accept-Language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate', 'X-Forwarded-For': '109.253.54.46', 'Host': 'XX.XX.100.66', 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110323 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.16', 'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'X-Real-Ip': 'XX.XX.54.46', 'Referer': 'http://XX.XX.100.66/'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.6.egg/tornado/web.py", line 861, in _execute
        getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.6.egg/tornado/web.py", line 941, in wrapper
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/blabla/src/python-sdk/examples/tornado/tornading.py", line 199, in get
        self.render("json_output.html", json = json.dumps({"error":"login"}))
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.6.egg/tornado/web.py", line 419, in render
        html = self.render_string(template_name, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.6.egg/tornado/web.py", line 520, in render_string
        current_user=self.current_user,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tornado-1.2-py2.6.egg/tornado/web.py", line 683, in current_user
        self._current_user = self.get_current_user()
      File "/home/blabla/src/python-sdk/examples/tornado/tornading.py", line 109, in get_current_user
        user = graph.get_object("me")
      File "/home/blabla/src/python-sdk/src/facebook.py", line 88, in get_object
        return self.request(id, args)
      File "/home/blabla/src/python-sdk/src/facebook.py", line 179, in request
        response["error"]["message"])
    GraphAPIError: Error validating access token.
[E 110407 20:44:20 web:1235] 500 GET /fl?access_token=122385271170470|2.teD_D9DV6gegmpgkbZI_Hg__.3600.1302206400-1592301191|GuXEs4YTqsCPDNFU4fhbWuwlvOQ (127.0.0.1) 2714.20ms
```

Try/except code:

           `try:

                   graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)

            except:

                    assert False, 'cougth it'`

Comment: Are you sure you're not catching (and swallowing) the exception somewhere else?

Comment: I don't know if you can do this in Python, but I would try to debug this with the debugger set to stop when and where an exception is thrown, and follow its path up the stack to check.

Comment: Sure, I can't catch it,the script stops working.   I'm new in Python, and first time I met this kind of exception. I think I can solve it by hacking the SDK code, but  I'm trying avoid it, if it's possible.

Comment: Could you post the full output when the problem occurs?

Comment: Full output doesn't matter, the issue about catching an “Uncaught exception”.UPD:  Ok, I add it to question.

Comment: When you say `try: ... except: ....` doesn't work, what do you mean exactly? Please show some code related to how you tried to catch the exception.

Comment: Don't use bare `except`, use `except GraphAPIError:`. If it doesn't get caught there you don't have it in the right place.

Comment: @Daenyth are you sure? In my experience bare except catching all exceptions. In any case, I'll try it.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. It'll also catch things like OverflowError and OutOfMemoryError...

Comment: Ok, I'll try, and  write comment here about results.

Comment: I checked it out, it was stupid, i tried hook it in wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the exception is thrown in another thread spawn by the API, check its source code.